# Android Studio overlays

Tags: java, android

I want to start creating long running applications. For instance, you choose some settings and then they are used while you browsing or playing a game. For example shortcut apps. You click somewhere in the corner, and something pop ups, with list of applications you want to go to.

My problem: I don't know how to create buttons, which would be on phone screen, like triggers, when you touch, something happens. I heard it's called overlays, but I couldn't manage to find tutorials about it.

Application example: Pie Control on Google Play. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jun.ace.piecontrol

Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [system alert window](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW) .

**example**

```
 View  mView = new View(this);
            WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
                    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
            params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.TOP;

            WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
            wm.addView(mView, params);
```

Comment: I get error when I try to run an app. Do I need to add any permissions ?

Comment: yes add <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" /> in manifest

Comment: don't know . I just give you a direction . hope it is helpful to  you.

Comment: Yes, it helped a lot :). Thanks.

Comment: welcome . please accept my answer if it is helpful. happy coding.